# Getting the object of selected element from a list of elements Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects populating a list of bootstrap cards as follows in x.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card card-accent-primary">
                   <div class="card-header">
                                            {{item.name}}
                        <label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-primary float-right mb-0">
                             <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" (change)="onSwitchItem($event)">
                             <span class="switch-label"></span>
                             <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body"></div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the items selected. Is there a way to get the item object in my x.component.ts?

My current implementation is assigning an index using angular property binding `[id]="item.index"` and accessing the items array using the index.

Comment: Do you want to make the cards as a child component and get the reference in the parent component?

Comment: Or you want to reference 'item' element in the class component?

Comment: I want to push the item into an array of selectedItems on checking the checkbox(here there switch) and remove on unchecking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement it as follows. Iterate over an array that 'keeps' the track of added child components. Then a check button can trigger the adding of a new element to the array and then ngFor will iterate again and add the new child component to the DOM.

**Parent component:**

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
   <child-card [item]=item></child-card>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
 child = [];

  add() {
    this.childs.splice(0,0,this.childs.length+1);
  }
}
```

**Child component:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card card-accent-primary">
                   <div class="card-header">
                                            {{item.name}}
                        <label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-primary float-right mb-0">
                             <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" (change)="onSwitchItem($event)">
                             <span class="switch-label"></span>
                             <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                       </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body"></div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'card-child',
    ....
}
....
export class cardChildComponent {
    @Input() item;
....
   }
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B6US1Mh8ySh0ECUn6Ppl?p=preview)**